# Play 2.6 + Slick 3.x experience and samples

Tags: scala, slick, playframework-2.6

I would like to ask some experienced Scala/Play programmers for an advice.

I have been happily using Play Framework 2.x for years with Java. Now I would like to learn Scala version of Play as I was told, that Play is much better with Scala than with Java.

I am actually really impressed by the language itself and I understand the connection between Scala and Play. However I have some problems adopting to database libraries used in Scala.

I tried some of them and in the end, I stayed with Slick as it looks the most promising in terms of ideas around Scala language. From Java-world, I was used to ORMs, especially Play Ebean. I liked the idea of object-graph loading, so I can load for example the Customer entity from DB and than traverse to Customer`s contracts, tickets and other realted entities. All the SQL selects and joins around, was done for me by ORM.

Now ... I fully understand, that Slick is NOT AN ORM. And I can live with that. However I would like to find some real-world application written in Play/Slick/Scala so I can observe the best-practices about using Slick. All I can find on internet, are very basic examples, which connect to database and do some basic insert/update/delete operations.

I cannot find any complex example of using the relations between tables and other things, which are more complex than just saving/loading rows from one table.

Any ideas on how to learn this?

Answer (score 1):

A few points - You don't learn the Scala version of Play but rather learn to write Scala

Yes, you made the right choice with regards to a relational mapping library - Slick. But there is yet another library called Quill which I guess is not yet production ready, but looks much more advanced than Slick.

https://github.com/getquill/quill

I have some basic examples of using Slick with Play. Though I'm not doing complex joins, here is a sample that might be of help to you!

https://github.com/joesan/plant-simulator/blob/master/app/com/inland24/plantsim/services/database/DBSchema.scala

If you are new to Scala, I would advice that you learn the language first before getting into Play, Slick and other Scala based libraries.

Comment: Thank you for anwser! I believe, that if you have experience with a few programming languages, which I do, you can learn another one quite easily. I prefer to learn the language by actually writing something (non-production apps for personal use or whatever). Anyway, I went through the lessons at https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/ to learn some basics and catch the differences comparing to other languages.